Как открыть web app через консоль?
Вот имеется простой бот у которого есть Web View, открывается оно по нажатию на кнопку. Так вот, как можно открыть web app про помощи консоли? Насколько я знаю, у телеграмма есть своя js библиотека связана с web app, но я там не нашел как открыть окно. Как это можно сделать? Только по классу?
